# How can I defeat Baal quickly?

Tags: ps2, disgaea

Is there any tactic or just an easy way to beat the lord of terror Baal? Just to clarify, I'm not asking about the prinny version.

I'm looking for the least time-consuming strategy.. yes, I'm that lazy :)

---

My current stats:

```
Laharl: level 1007
Divine Majin: level 1000
Priere and Marjoly: level 2000/2500
Captured dragons (about 7): level 1000-4500
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest way that is least time consuming is to just use extremely levelled characters. Baal is only level 4000, after all.

Of course, you don't have such right now. So to do this in the quickest fashion will probably involve just getting *bigger* and **badder** dragons until you get the *biggest* and **baddest** ***dragons***. You have some at level 4500, and you have access to the Beauty Palace stage which has *big dragons*. Provided you weaken the target a bit, it's possible to capture a stronger dragon with a weaker dragon. I've never personally tried this strategy, so I don't remember the general threshold that you should be shooting for - I seem to recall it being around 500-1000 levels higher as being safe.

So, using a combination of Stronger Enemy bills and throwing dragons into each other, capture progressively **badder dragons** until you eventually capture a level 9999 ***dragon***. Consequently, use it to capture 9 more. With 10 level 9999 ***dragons***.  and good equipment (even if not leveled completely through the Item World), you should be able to take down a level 4000 Baal without too much problem. Don't forget to pass the Weaker Enemy bills to drop his level back down.

Of course, you probably don't need to go all the way to 10 level 9999 ***dragons***. . You could probably accomplish it at a lower level and with possibly fewer **dragons**, but if you want a mostly guaranteed victory, this is about the way to do it. It may take some doing to handle the right threshold for capturing, but the time spent figuring that is shorter than how long you'd spend building up characters normally.

Comment: thanks, this is probably the best answer, though I'll wait and see if any others would come up...